# ¿Se puede crear 1 Web Form de C# y 1 de Visual Basi en ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Estoy empezando a "programar" en ASP.net y me surge la pregunta de si se pueden crear 2 Web Forms diferentes, es decir, cada uno con un "lenguaje", uno con C# y el otro con Visual Basic.

Y también saber si hay mucha diferencia entre ambos lenguajes (C# y Visual Basic), además de la diferencia de la sintaxis.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puede crear 2 clases diferentes o WebForms con C # / VB.NET en el mismo proyecto, pero puede crear otro proyecto dentro de la solución y usar VB.NET.
Por lo tanto, es posible usar diferentes idiomas pero necesita usar diferentes proyectos para eso.

Aunque C # y VB.NET son sintácticamente muy diferentes, ahí es donde terminan las diferencias. Microsoft desarrolló ambos idiomas para formar parte de la misma plataforma de desarrollo de .NET Framework. ... Compilan en el mismo lenguaje intermedio (IL), que se ejecuta en las mismas bibliotecas de tiempo de ejecución de .NET Framework.

Comment: Perfecto Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Thanks, I use some translator to my answers but I hope it will be understandable.

Comment: En un solo proyecto, no se pude usar paginas VB y C#, ¿estas seguro que No?

Comment: 100%, no puede usar VB.NET y C # dentro del MISMO PROYECTO, pero puede crear otro proyecto y usarlos en la MISMA SOLUCIÓN

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278024/mixing-c-sharp-vb-in-the-same-project